# How to run loop.create_task() along with bot commands?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have an async function with a blocking `while` loop, and it is supposed to be a background task that checks for new tweets and sends them in a specific discord channel. I start the function with `bot.loop.create_task(function())`, and it works like it should. However, when I try to do a bot command in discord, the bot doesn't respond and nothing happens. It seems like the background task is blocking everything. Here is the background task:

```
async def user_tweets():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    while True:
        with open('data/data.json') as account_file:
            data = json.load(account_file)
        # loop for every user
        for discord_user in data:
            for twitter_users_dict in data[discord_user]:
                twitter_user = ''.join([key for key in twitter_users_dict.keys()])
                value = twitter_users_dict.get(twitter_user)
                try:
                    tweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name=twitter_user,
                                              # 200 is the maximum allowed count
                                              count=200,
                                              include_rts=value['retweets'],
                                              tweet_mode='extended',
                                              exclude_replies=not value['replies'],
                                              include_entities=True
                                              )
                except tweepy.TweepError:
                    twitter_feed_channel = bot.get_channel(779894858478649344)
                    await twitter_feed_channel.send('Request limit is probably exceeded, waiting 5 min before trying again')
                    time.sleep(300)
                    continue

                for entry in data[discord_user]:
                    if entry.get(twitter_user):
                        entry[twitter_user]['Last tweet'] = info.id
                with open('data/data.json', 'w') as account_file:
                    json.dump(data, account_file)

                twitter_feed_channel = bot.get_channel(829886945982939207)
                user_to_ping = await bot.fetch_user(discord_user)
                await twitter_feed_channel.send(f'{user_to_ping.mention} https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/{info.id}')
                print('sent ' + discord_user + twitter_user + str(value))
        time.sleep(1)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better way to do this? I just want to have a background task which runs whenever the bot runs and also have the bot respond to commands.

Comment: Please add the function, but if it's [blocking](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean) then you should run it in a separate thread.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I have included some of the function, it basically loops through a json file and checks for new tweets and when it detects new tweets it send a message through  discord. I tried using the threading module but I don't know how to incorporate async with it

Comment: Do not use `time.sleep` within asynchronous code, use `await asyncio.sleep(n)` instead. You either use all async or all sync, mixing both is not the best idea.

Comment: Also maybe use the discord.py built-in task extension: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html

Comment: I tried `await asyncio.sleep()` but it still doesn't make a difference. I have also already tried using tasks, however I need to specify the time between loops which I do not want. The only reason it worked with tasks is because there was a pause between the time the function finished and the time it is scheduled to restart.

Comment: I guess there is a way to run a "blocking" coroutine in a non-blocking way, I'll write an answer but I think it's not a good design solution

Answer (score 0):

Mixing blocking with asynchronous code is not really the best idea, I'd submit each blocking function to a separate thread/process. Nonetheless you can run a blocking coroutine in the following way:

```py
import asyncio

async def user_tweets():
    ...


async def run_blocking_coro(coro):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    def wrapper():  # submit this to a thread
        fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop)
        return fut.result()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, wrapper)  # asyncio.to_thread for python 3.9+


asyncio.create_task(run_blocking_coro(user_tweets())
```